# Unique Class or extend Class or Subclass in Python Django?

Tags: python, django, class, model

Unique Class or extend Class or Subclass in Python Django?

In the following situation, I have a feeling I need to ?extend? the Migration class instead of re-stating it in the second module. Or is a child class needed?

A goal here: To create a postgres table called venues. There is already a models/venues.py that seems to be set up ok.

**migrations/0001_initial.py:**

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    initial = True
    dependencies = [('auth', '0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length'),]
    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='User',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, ...)),
                ('password', models.CharField(max_length=128, ...)),
                ...
```

**migrations/0002_venue.py:**

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [('app', '0001_initial'),]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Venue',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True...)),
            ('name', models.CharField(blank=True ...)),
            ('address', models.CharField(blank=True...)),
            ...
```

** models/venue.py:**

```
class Venue(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True...)
    address = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True...)
    city = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, ...)
    zip = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True...)
    #gps_coords = models.CharField(blank=True...)
    gps_lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14...)
    gps_long = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14...)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, ...)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True...)
    contact_phone = models.CharField(blank=True...)
    contact_email = models.EmailField(blank=True...)
    contact_name = models.CharField(blank=True...)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + " " + self.description
```

Help?

Comment: It is not clear to me at all what you aim to achieve.

Comment: Usually migration are created from the model and they work. Why have you chosen an other path?

Comment: Thx for the comments. I'll edit question to show model creation code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you create your model class, you need to run `python manage.py makemigrations` and django will create a migration file. (Make sure you've added the app to the INSTALLED_APPS on project's settings.py

Once you run the makemigrations, you'll be able to see the migration file in your app's migrations folder. Having this file doesn't mean the table is created. It just represents the set of instructions that'll run on database when you run the migrate command.

When you have the new migration file, you can run `python manage.py migrate`, and that migration file will be applied to your database.

You can run the showmigrations command to see which migrations are applied on your database.

`python manage.py showmigrations`
or
`python manage.py showmigrations app_name`